# How to automatically import data from Excel to Postgres everyday?

Tags: sql, excel, postgresql, pgadmin

How do I make it so that as I update my excel files, the data is auto imported into postgres sql.

Comment: You need software that performs this import.  pgadmin won't do it automatically.  Excel uses a form of Visual Basic to create [macros](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/quick-start-create-a-macro-741130ca-080d-49f5-9471-1e5fb3d581a8).  You can create your own macro or try to find a macro that does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need an ETL or to write some software.

I had the same problem in the past, I used Talend open studio. It is free, but not immediate if you are new to this kind of product: https://www.talend.com/products/talend-open-studio/